# Spooky behaviour of siunitx in a table

Tags: tables, siunitx

#### ! *Updated* !

1-as asked by @marmot, the code has been updated
2-as pointed out by @egreg, the code has been updated
3-a new doubt has arisen meanwhile! See "Second Part" Below!

### *Original question*, **now** the *first* part of the question!

I'm trying to compile a table that centers it elements around the decimal point.  For that purpose, I'm using the "`S`" option of `siunitx` in `tabular`, as specified below. This table is placed on a two-column page - hence the `table`* function.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbered,print,index]
\usepackage{siunitx} % use this package module for SI units
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}% table* allows a table to spawn the entire width of the page.
    \label{C3-table:2}
    \caption{Spectroscopic Parameters and Relative Energies Calculated at the MP2/6-311++G(d,p) Level of Theory for the Lowest-Energy Conformers of Synephrine}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lSSSS}
        \toprule
 &Rotamer $ I $   &Rotamer $ II $ &Rotamer $ III $&Rotamer $ IV $ \\
   \midrule
$ A^{a} $      &3065.6858(11)$ ^{b} $   &3064.85192(78) &2479.83963(70) &2478.4259(21)\\
$ B $          &540.46172(20)   &538.62660(18)  &614.51086(19)  &613.38156(16)\\
$ C  $         &498.99506(17)   &501.10248(14)  &582.56681(33)  &584.25597(24)\\
$ \chi_{aa} $  &  2.3300(70)    &  2.3960(63)   &  1.3220(75)   &  1.257(35)\\
$ \chi_{bb} $  & -2.9628(70)    & -2.7624(76)   & -3.7288(81)   & -3.514(23)\\
$ \chi_{cc} $  &  0.6328(70)    &  0.3724(76)   &  2.4068(81)   &  2.257(23)\\
$ \mu_{a}^{c} $&Y               &Y              &N              &N\\
$ \mu_{b}^{c} $&Y               &Y              &Y              &Y\\
$ \mu_{c}^{c} $&Y               &Y              &N              &Y\\
$ N^{e} $      &24              &26             &19             &25\\
$\sigma^{e}$   &2.3             &2.3            &3.5            &3.3\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption*{ \small $ ^{a}A $, $ B $, and $ C $ are the rotational constants (in $ MHz $); $ \chi_{aa} $, $ \chi_{bb} $, and $ \chi_{cc} $ are elements of the $ ^{14} $N nuclear quadrupole coupling tensor (in $ MHz $). $ ^{b} $Standard errors indicated in parentheses in units of the last digit. $ ^{c} $Y (yes) and N (no) indicate whether $ a- $, $ b- $, and $ c- $type transitions were observed for each structure. $ ^{d} $Number of fitted transitions. $ ^{e} $Root mean square of the fit (in $ kH $z).}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I noticed that using the using `\begin{tabular}{lSSSS}` option forces a lot of empty spaces in the column (understandable), but the end result is quite awful! Observe that an "e" was "eaten away" using this tabulation!

[image: using \begin{tabular}{lSSSS}]
Using the `{lllll}`, for instance, renders the table correctly, but unaligned

[image: using \begin{tabular}{llll}]

Any insight/solution to this problem would be much appreciated!

### Second part of the Question!

When applying a variation of egreg's code,

```
\begin{table*}[p] % table* allows a table to spawn the entire width of the page.

\caption{Spectroscopic Parameters and Relative Energies Calculated at the 
    MP2/6-311++G(d,p) Level of Theory for the Lowest-Energy Conformers of Synephrine}
\label{C3-table:4} % should go after \caption

\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{6}{S[table-format=4.5(2)]} @{} }
    \toprule
    & {Rotamer $I$} & {Rotamer $II$} & {Rotamer $III$} & {Rotamer $IV$} & {Rotamer $V$} & {Rotamer $VI$} \\
    \midrule
    $A$\tn{a} & 2619.31951(91)\TN{b} &  2621.43704(81) & 2431.79192(93) & 2429.8036(26) & 1751.6139(17) & 1749.29934(76)\\
    $B$ & 417.815936(90) &  416.712685(80) & 401.522388(86) & 399.97472(24) & 491.43186(17) & 491.01374(10) \\
    $C$ & 386.003079(87) & 387.043532(75) & 383.211109(81) & 385.16449(25) & 464.06642(12) & 465.271378(96)\\
    $\chi_{aa}$ & 2.524(18) & 2.587(16) & 2.537(19) & 2.580(72) & 1.573(47) & 1.596(12) \\
    $\chi_{bb}$ &-3.054(13) &-2.778(12) &-4.767(15) &-4.764(62) &-1.187(31) &-0.9142(93)\\
    $\chi_{cc}$ & 0.530(13) & 0.250(12) & 2.231(14) & 2.184(62) &-0.387(31) &-0.6818(93)\\
    $\mu_{a}$\tn{c} & {Y}   & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {N} & {N} \\
    $\mu_{b}$\tn{c} & {Y}   & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} \\
    $\mu_{c}$\tn{c} & {Y}   & {Y} & {Y} & {N} & {N} & {Y} \\
    $N$\tn{d}       & \num{31} & \num{32} & \num{18} \num{20} & \num{14} & \num{20} \\
    $\sigma$\tn{e}  & \num{2.1} & \num{1.8} & \num{2.3} & \num{3.1} & \num{1.7} & \num{2.1} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\raggedright\footnotesize

\begin{enumerate}[label=\tn{\alph*},leftmargin=*]
    \item $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the rotational constants (in \si{MHz});
    $\chi_{aa}$, $\chi_{bb}$, and $\chi_{cc}$ are elements of the $^{14}$N 
    nuclear quadrupole coupling tensor (in \si{MHz}).

    \item Standard errors indicated in parentheses in units of the last digit. 

    \item Y (yes) and N (no) indicate whether $a$-, $b$-, and $c$-type transitions
    were observed for each structure.

    \item Number of fitted transitions.

    \item Root mean square of the fit (in \si{kHz}).
\end{enumerate}

\end{table*}
```

I've found out that it's way too big!

[image]

There are a couple options here:
1- I tried `pdflscape` but somehow it didn't work properly (still working on it!)
2- Font resizing (ugh!)
3- Ask for a "a-ha!" solution from the community!

Comment: Please make your snippet compilable: add the documentclass, `\begin{document}`,`\end{document}`, and explain where one can find `tabular.sty`.

Comment: Try `\sisetup{table-format=4.5(2)}`.

Comment: @TeXnician, could you provide a simple example in order to see how that option is integrated?

Comment: @Strelok I will provide an example when yours is compilable, i.e. when I can test my assumption. Currently your example does not compile (look e.g. at the documentclass; and adding article results in errors with the headers of your table which should be surrounded by braces).

Comment: You shouldn’t pile up problems in the same question. Clearly, six columns with eleven digit numbers are likely not to fit in the text width, just as you can’t squeeze an elephant into a suitcase. Smaller type isn’t a feasible choice, so sideways seems the choice. In this case, use `tabular` and remove the extracolsep bit. Because of the table notes, you should consider `threeparttable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibly better way to typeset your table.

The `S` columns should be given the number of digits; the last five rows should have all centered entries (aligning the numbers in the last two rows at the period would mean nothing).

I also suggest separating carefully the note markers from exponents. There are also several other fixes (note `\si{MHz}`, for instance).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % use this package module for SI units
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\TN}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\tn{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}% table* allows a table to spawn the entire width of the page.

\caption{Spectroscopic Parameters and Relative Energies Calculated at the 
  MP2/6-311++G(d,p) Level of Theory for the Lowest-Energy Conformers of Synephrine}
\label{C3-table:2} % should go after \caption

\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{S[table-format=4.5(2)]} @{} }
\toprule
 & {Rotamer $I$} & {Rotamer $II$} & {Rotamer $III$} & {Rotamer $IV$} \\
\midrule
$A$\tn{a}       & 3065.6858(11)\TN{b} & 3064.85192(78) & 2479.83963(70) & 2478.4259(21)\\
$B$             &  540.46172(20)      &  538.62660(18) &  614.51086(19) &  613.38156(16)\\
$C$             &  498.99506(17)      &  501.10248(14) &  582.56681(33) &  584.25597(24)\\
$\chi_{aa}$     &    2.3300(70)       &    2.3960(63)  &    1.3220(75)  &    1.257(35)\\
$\chi_{bb}$     &   -2.9628(70)       &   -2.7624(76)  &   -3.7288(81)  &   -3.514(23)\\
$\chi_{cc}$     &    0.6328(70)       &    0.3724(76)  &    2.4068(81)  &    2.257(23)\\
$\mu_{a}$\tn{c} & {Y}                 & {Y}           & {N}             & {N} \\
$\mu_{b}$\tn{c} & {Y}                 & {Y}           & {Y}             & {Y} \\
$\mu_{c}$\tn{c} & {Y}                 & {Y}           & {N}             & {Y} \\
$N$\tn{e}       & \num{24}            & \num{26}      & \num{19}        & \num{25} \\
$\sigma$\tn{e}  & \num{2.3}           & \num{2.3}     & \num{3.5}       & \num{3.3} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\raggedright\footnotesize

\begin{enumerate}[label=\tn{\alph*},leftmargin=*]
\item $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the rotational constants (in \si{MHz});
      $\chi_{aa}$, $\chi_{bb}$, and $\chi_{cc}$ are elements of the $^{14}$N 
      nuclear quadrupole coupling tensor (in \si{MHz}).

\item Standard errors indicated in parentheses in units of the last digit. 

\item Y (yes) and N (no) indicate whether $a$-, $b$-, and $c$-type transitions
      were observed for each structure.

\item Number of fitted transitions.

\item Root mean square of the fit (in \si{kHz}).
\end{enumerate}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're quite right, egreg! Thanks a lot for the heads up! The table looks gorgeous!

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the story shorter, I put the code with TeXnician's comment, and I'll be happy to remove this post. Apart from this trick, you need to put the items in the first row in braces, see siunitx manual table 7.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbered,print,index]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % use this package module for SI units
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\sisetup{table-format=4.5(2)}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}% table* allows a table to spawn the entire width of the page.
    \label{C3-table:2}
    \caption{Spectroscopic Parameters and Relative Energies Calculated at the MP2/6-311++G(d,p) Level of Theory for the Lowest-Energy Conformers of Synephrine}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lSSSS}
      \toprule
 & {Rotamer $ I $}   & {Rotamer $ II $} & {Rotamer $ III $} & {Rotamer $ IV $} \\
   \midrule
$ A^{a} $      &3065.6858(11)$ ^{b} $   &3064.85192(78) &2479.83963(70) &2478.4259(21)\\
$ B $          &540.46172(20)   &538.62660(18)  &614.51086(19)  &613.38156(16)\\
$ C  $         &498.99506(17)   &501.10248(14)  &582.56681(33)  &584.25597(24)\\
$ \chi_{aa} $  &  2.3300(70)    &  2.3960(63)   &  1.3220(75)   &  1.257(35)\\
$ \chi_{bb} $  & -2.9628(70)    & -2.7624(76)   & -3.7288(81)   & -3.514(23)\\
$ \chi_{cc} $  &  0.6328(70)    &  0.3724(76)   &  2.4068(81)   &  2.257(23)\\
$ \mu_{a}^{c} $& {Y}               & {Y}              & {N}              & {N}\\
$ \mu_{b}^{c} $& {Y}               & {Y}              & {Y}              & {Y}\\
$ \mu_{c}^{c} $& {Y}               & {Y}              & {N}              & {Y}\\
$ N^{e} $      &24              &26             &19             &25\\
$\sigma^{e}$   &2.3             &2.3            &3.5            &3.3\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption*{ \small $ ^{a}A $, $ B $, and $ C $ are the rotational constants (in $ MHz $); $ \chi_{aa} $, $ \chi_{bb} $, and $ \chi_{cc} $ are elements of the $ ^{14} $N nuclear quadrupole coupling tensor (in $ MHz $). $ ^{b} $Standard errors indicated in parentheses in units of the last digit. $ ^{c} $Y (yes) and N (no) indicate whether $ a- $, $ b- $, and $ c- $type transitions were observed for each structure. $ ^{d} $Number of fitted transitions. $ ^{e} $Root mean square of the fit (in $ kH $z).}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TeXnician If you want, I can remove this post and you can upload your answer.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you both very much, TeXnician and marmot!

Comment: I will not, egreg was faster and better. But *please* don't do a global `\sisetup`. Doing it locally is much better does avoid side effects.

Comment: Usually, table captions should be *above* the table, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Bernard Absolutely! I did not pay any attention to this, all I did was too make the code compilable. Certainly egreg's take on this is much better than this. As I wrote, I'll be happy to remove it if I'm asked to.

Comment: @marmot: In my opinion, if the six first rows can be aligned on the decimal dot, the last two should not, but rather be centred, as they seem to be of a different nature

Comment: @Bernard Yes, you're right, just tell me if I should remove this post. (I was really just concerned with the fact that the `e` letters in `Rotamer` got swallowed, and with fixing the OP's code such that it runs through.)

Comment: I don't think so. You show  an interesting way for  run-in table footnotes.